# PostgreSQL hangs while executing DDL without log message

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I have Postgresql-9.2.10 on CentOS.

I experience the following error:

```
DETAIL: Multiple failures --- write error might be permanent.
ERROR: could not open file "pg_tblspc / 143862353 / PG_9.2_201204301 / 16439 / 199534370_fsm": No such file or directory
```

This happens since I stopped the PostgreSQL service, ran `pg_resetxlog` and started the service. The logs in `pg_log` look good, and the service is listed without any problem.

DML works well , but not a DDL statement like `CREATE TABLE`, otherwise an error message is thrown or nothing is visible in the logs in `pg_log`.

If I try to create a table, there is no reaction, and it looks like the statement is blocked by a lock.

So I tried the following query to look for locks:

```
SELECT blocked_locks.pid AS blocked_pid,
    blocked_activity.usename AS blocked_user,
    blocking_locks.pid AS blocking_pid,
    blocking_activity.usename AS blocking_user,
    blocked_activity.query AS blocked_statement,
    blocking_activity.query AS blocking_statement
FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks blocked_locks
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocked_activity ON blocked_activity.pid = blocked_locks.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks blocking_locks 
ON blocking_locks.locktype = blocked_locks.locktype
    AND blocking_locks.DATABASE IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.DATABASE
    AND blocking_locks.relation IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.relation
    AND blocking_locks.page IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.page
    AND blocking_locks.tuple IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.tuple
    AND blocking_locks.virtualxid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.virtualxid
    AND blocking_locks.transactionid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.transactionid
    AND blocking_locks.classid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.classid
    AND blocking_locks.objid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objid
    AND blocking_locks.objsubid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objsubid
    AND blocking_locks.pid != blocked_locks.pid
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocking_activity ON blocking_activity.pid = blocking_locks.pid
WHERE NOT blocked_locks.granted;
```

Comment: The error seems more filesystem related that lock related.  Have you checked that the file path mentioned exists, is owned by the postgres user and has correct permisions

Comment: Is there a way to know about the status of the postgresql addition pg_log?

Comment: "create table" statement is to just wait ppuninde without a response, pg_log yet it does not appear in the message. Only one sentence is simply to create an empty table.

Answer (score 0):

You probably corrupted the PostgreSQL cluster with `pg_resetxlog`. How exactly did you run the command?

I would restore from the last good backup.